# Program to get the lowest number in a file

Tags: java, file, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to make the program access a file name "highscore.txt", then:

1. Write a new number in the file
2. Get the lowest value of a list of numbers in the file.

I am new to Java so I barely know how to even access the file.

I got code that I believe should work, but when I run the program it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at game.game.main(game.java:91)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is line 84 - 94, and the code I got.

```
84: Writer wr = new FileWriter("highscore.txt");
85:            wr.write(tries);
86:            wr.close();
87:            lowest = tries;
88:            File file = new File("highscore.txt");
89: Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
90: while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
91:    numb = inputFile.nextDouble();
92:    if (numb < lowest) lowest = number;
93: }
94: inputFile.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question looks like homework to me. While asking homework questions is perfectly fine, there are some good guidelines for asking homework questions here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812). Summarized, they are: make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first; ask about specific problems with your existing code; let us know that the question is homework; make sure your class allows using Q&A for help; don't copy and paste an answer's code without first understanding what it does and how it works.

Comment: Even if this isn't homework, the rules "make an attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "ask about _specific_ problems with your _existing_ code" still apply.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try overwriting the value in the file instead of writing a new line

Comment: In addition to the homework guidelines above, make sure to ask you teacher to TA.  They need to know what you are having trouble with in class so they can help you learn better.

Comment: Read all of the file, add your new entry, sort the entries, discard least, write out new file.

Comment: Actually, I am needing this to make a game. I program as a hobby.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your file? The next token you are trying to read with `inputFile.nextDouble()` probably isn't a double.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Collections` class. It implements a static `sort()` method that does what you want: sorting numbers.
A quick and dirty code would look like this (supposing you've got a number in each line):

```
String line = readLine();
while(line != null){
  numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
  line = readLine();
}
Collections.sort(numberList);
```

Now just pick the first number from `numberList`.

Comment: As I said, I am new at Java, so I don't have any idea what readLine() means, or how to use classes.

Comment: readLine() doesn't exist as such. It's supposed to be a method of your own that reads a line from a file. I can't remember the exact process of reading a file in Java right now.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for trying to help me out anyway.